# Vue/Vite - Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory (unplugin-vue-components)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vite

I am running into a memory issue when building using Vite:

> Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

This is the output:

```js
<--- Last few GCs --->

[23466:0x5e196b0]    37408 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 489.9 (502.1) -> 488.2 (501.6) MB, 1271.9 / 0.0 ms  (+ 3.8 ms in 6 steps since start of marking, biggest step 1.3 ms, walltime since start of marking 1318 ms) (average mu = 0.368, current mu = 0.040) allo[23466:0x5e196b0]    38726 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 490.5 (503.2) -> 489.9 (503.1) MB, 1315.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.220, current mu = 0.002) allocation failure GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xb06730 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa1b6d0  [node]
 3: 0xce1dd0 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xce2177 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xe997e5  [node]
 6: 0xea94ad v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 7: 0xeac1ae v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
 8: 0xe6d6ea v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]
 9: 0x11e658c v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInOldGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
10: 0x15da0d9  [node]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Below is my `vite.config.js` file:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import Components from "unplugin-vue-components/vite";
import { PrimeVueResolver } from "unplugin-vue-components/resolvers";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        Components({
            resolvers: [PrimeVueResolver()]
        }),
        laravel({
            input: "resources/js/app.js",
            refresh: true
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false
                }
            }
        })
    ]
});
```

The problem seems related to the [unplugin-vue-components](https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-vue-components) package. If I remove the below from the config file, it works:

```js
Components({
    resolvers: [PrimeVueResolver()]
}),
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was caused by [enabling source maps for sentry](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/react/sourcemaps/uploading/vite/) so I can get more readable stack traces...

Everything's fine after I disabled it.

EDIT: I actually removed everything sentry-related from my vite.config.js

Comment: That is not a solution.  We should still be able to build source maps on memory constrained build servers.

Comment: You're most probably right, I was trying to point out it was the problem not that I have a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I was wrong in my first message.

I kept increasing memory until the npm process was way over 20gb and no sign of slowing down.
By adding the following to `vite.config.js` it was solved.

```
export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        watch: {
            followSymlinks: false,
```

Previous response

> Came across this today and what worked for me was a change to the
> "scripts" section in package.json  `"dev":"npx cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192 vite"` from  `"dev":"vite"`

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue with react. The issue was on tsconfig.json. Here is the full explanation
https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2433#issuecomment-1475853535